# Objective-C: Memory issue when import large amount of contacts from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, import-contacts

I'm trying to import contacts from NSData object in ARC using the code below:

```
- (void) importAllVcard: (NSData *)VcardData
{
    NSString *vCardString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:VcardData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CFDataRef vCardData = (__bridge CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(book);
    CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData);

    NSArray *array = (__bridge NSArray*)vCardPeople;
    for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, index);
            ABAddressBookAddRecord(book, person, NULL);
        }
    }

    CFRelease(vCardPeople);
    CFRelease(defaultSource);
    CFRelease(book);
}
```

But I face a problem even before I do any of  the importing operations.

If I want to import 50,000 contacts, when my code is trying to create `CFArrayRef` for my contact data using `ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation`, the memory will keep increasing and reach almost 250MB (Xcode memory debug navigator data).

This is too high for me, because I have other tasks run at the same time might occupy a large memory. So I want to reduce the memory usage before I start importing it.

I was trying to decrease the memory by release some CFReferences that I don't need when importing the contacts like that large `CFArrayRef` before the importing loop, but memory not going down.

For the test purpose, I commented out the importing loop, only get the array of the contacts. When the whole process done, this view controller will disappear, and next view controller shows up, then the memory back to 80MB.

Is there any possible way to decrease the memory to almost 80MB level before I start importing contacts saved in `NSArray` without change the view controller.

Comment: Well converting your data into a string and then back into data for no reason is definitely a waste of memory

Comment: Hi,dan. Sorry I don't quit understand the problem, because it seems like that two lines of code are not significantly increasing my memory.  @dan

Comment: I'd check for leaks using the static analzyer. The unnecessary [vCardString dataUsingEncoding...] will end up in an autorelease pool,

Comment: @Xin Those two lines waste a lot of memory. You needlessly create a very large string (`vCardString`) and a 2nd copy of the data (`vCardData`). Just use `VcardData` when calling `ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation`.

Comment: BTW - if you don't need to support iOS 8 or earlier you should use the new Contacts framework and the `CNContactVCardSerialization` class.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, rmaddy, I changed my code, but during the saving process, the memory keep increasing, is this the proper way to save all contacts in one loop?